# How to avoid text disappearing when using CGAffineTransform?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make a button rotate in my app, and I have the following piece of code:

```
- (void)setFrameForButton:(UIButton *)ok {
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isWildcat]) {
    if([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        ok.frame = CGRectMake(244, 840, 280, 20);
        if (wasChanging) ok.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.50);
    }
    else {
        ok.frame = CGRectMake(372, 584, 280, 20);
        if (wasChanging) ok.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.50);
    }
}
else {
    ok.frame = CGRectMake(15.0, 375.0 ,280.0, 20.0);
}
if (wasChanging) wasChanging = NO;
}

- (void)window:(id)window willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(int)orientation duration:(double)duration {
wasChanging = YES;
[self setFrameForButton:btn];
}
```

Although when I rotate the position it should be is changed and after some following rotations the text at my button disappears. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the issue, but try setting the `autoresizesSubviews` property of yor `UIButton` to `NO`. This might stop the `UIButton` from trying to transform its text in any weird way and mess it up.